# How to test that method is called on mock?

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I have a class that looks like this:

```
from operators import Operation
class A():
    def process(self, message):
        Operation(message).execute()
```

and I have this test:

```
class TestA(unittest.TestCase):

   @mock.patch("path.to.A.Operation")
   def test_create_assertion_processor(self, mock_operation):
      message = {}
      mock_operation_instance = mock.MagicMock
      mock_operation.return_value = mock.MagicMock(return_value = mock_operation_instance)

      A().process(message)

      mock_operation.assert_called_once_with(message)
      mock_operation_instance.execute.assert_called()
```

The last line does not work. I get:

```
AttributeError: type object 'MagicMock' has no attribute 'execute'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is only a typo, brackets are missing when instancing your first `MagicMock`

```py
class TestA(unittest.TestCase):

   @mock.patch("path.to.A.Operation")
   def test_create_assertion_processor(self, mock_operation):
      message = {}
      mock_operation_instance = mock.MagicMock()  # missing bracket here.
      mock_operation.return_value = mock.MagicMock(return_value = mock_operation_instance)

      A().process(message)

      mock_operation.assert_called_once_with(message)
      mock_operation_instance.execute.assert_called()
```